# tsql day of week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I've been asked for an T-SQL challenge, I need to get the equivalent day on next month based on day position like this:

Today is 18/07/2011 in other words is the third Monday of this month...

Now I need to get the third Monday of next month (15/08/2011) on a SQL Server query.

This is like google calendar's recurrence rules.

I've been trying a lot of formulas but it gets very complicated, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be: 1) figure out which day it is (3rd monday of the month) 2) Find the first of the same type of day next month (ie. first monday) 3) If we want 2nd or above, increase date by the appropriate multiple of 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help someone, if you want to get the ordinal date any number of months from now, I've created this function as a combination of all of your advices:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fncSameDayOfWeekAnotherMonth] (@Date datetime, @Months int)
RETURNS datetime
AS BEGIN
  declare @FONM datetime,  @day TinyInt, @ordinal tinyint, @FDM datetime, @result datetime

  Set @FONM = DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,@Months,@Date))-1),DATEADD(mm,@Months,@Date))--first day of month
  Set @day = datepart(weekday,@Date)+7
  set @ordinal=ceiling( cast(datepart(day,@Date)as float)/7 )--ordinal day
  set @FDM = DateAdd(day, ((@day -DatePart(weekday, @FONM))%7), @FONM)--first day of week (monday, friday, etc) on month

  set @result = DateAdd(day, (@ordinal-1)*7, @FDM)

    RETURN case when DATEDIFF(month, @Date, @result) >  @Months  then DateAdd(day, (@ordinal-2)*7, @FDM) else @result end --if result exceeds number of months just subtract one week from ordinal

END
```

it receives date and number of months, gets the ordinal number of the day and the first day of the month you want. With this last one finds the first occurrence of the week day in that month, then it calculates corresponding ordinal date any months from your date.

I know it has a lot of code and might be improved but at least it works pretty well.

Comment: In cases when `@Date` is the 5th occurrence of some weekday in its month and the corresponding day is undefined for the calculated month, your function returns the 4th occurrence of the same weekday, rather than NULL, but I understand that is your particular preference for such cases. Otherwise this function seems to work well, except that it fails on year transition(s). I think that could be fixed by using `DATEDIFF(mm, …) > @Month` instead of `MONTH(…) > MONTH(…) + @Month`.

Comment: which date didn't work?, I've tested on several cases and it works through next year

Comment: `SELECT dbo.fncSameDayOfWeekAnotherMonth('20111129', 3)`. I should have said, it fails *in certain cases* on year transition. The 'certain cases' are when a date is a weekday #5 and you specify a month that will have a lesser number than the original one and doesn't have that weekday #5. That is why DATEDIFF would be more reliable.

Comment: You're right, even with datediff I get a wrong date, I'll have to figure it out

Comment: I was using datediff with parameters backwards, now is fixed and edited, thank you @Andriy M

Comment: It is laudable, of course, that you have decided to contribute to the community by accepting your own answer. Your solution is definitely better than others. But it is so merely because it solves a more universal problem than what has been asked in your question. You've probably somewhat robbed yourself of a chance of benefiting from the community support. Had you posted the more universal problem as a new question, like I suggested you, you could possibly have received better alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

This syntak will calculate the same day next week and put in null if it doesn't exists

```
declare @t datetime

set @t = '2008-01-29'

select case (datepart(day, @t)+ 6) / 7
           when (datepart(day, @t + 28)+ 6) / 7 then @t + 28
           when (datepart(day, @t + 35)+ 6) / 7 then @t + 35
           else null end
```

Comment: +1 for the idea of returning NULL in case of an indefinite day.

Comment: Andry - Thx for noticing it, I posted it after points were given. So I didn't expect I would get any credit at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnSameDayOfWeekNextMonth (@Date datetime)
RETURNS datetime
AS BEGIN
  RETURN (
    SELECT
      DATEADD(WEEK,
              CASE (MONTH(ApproxDate) - MONTH(@Date) + 12) % 12
                WHEN 2 THEN -1
                ELSE ThisDayNum - (DAY(ApproxDate) - 1) / 7
              END,
              ApproxDate)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        ThisDayNum = (DAY(@Date) - 1) / 7,
        ApproxDate = DATEADD(WEEK, 5, @Date)
    ) s
  )
END
```

This function implements the following logic:

1. Get an approximate date as the given date plus exactly 5 weeks.
2. Get the number of the day of the week in the given date's month.
3. If the month of the approximated date is 2 months after the given date's month, subtract one week from the approximated date and return the result.
4. Otherwise get the same as #2, but for the approximated date (instead of the given date).
5. Get the difference between #2 and #4.
6. Subtract #5, as the number of weeks, from the approximated date and return the result.

The Step #3 means that if the current date is a fifth something, then the resulting date will be the fourth same weekday of the following month, because the fifth one will be impossible. **Update:** [@t-clausen.dk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741022/tsql-day-of-week/6749242#6749242) has offered, in my opinion, a better idea of returning NULLs in such cases. The above function can be easily modified to follow the same convention: the `…WHEN 2 THEN -1…` part should simply be changed to `…WHEN 2 THEN NULL…`.

Comment: hi, any idea to jump any number of months?, ex. third monday of 4 months from now

Comment: @Milox: Yes, I've got one very vague idea which I'm currently working on trying to base it off the above solution. So far the problem proves to differ considerably from your original one, even though the two are very much related. If you are really interested in solving it, I would recommend you to post your request as a new question. Someone might very well be quicker than me.

Comment: Thank you @Andriy M, I've already posted a function I've developed that solves that scenario, is not so clear but it works. Please take a look below

Answer (score 1):

Luckily for you, I had to do this once: http://blog.prokrams.com/2007/06/18/determining-the-ordinal-of-a-weekday/

```
Create Function fn_ReturnOrdinalDay( @TestDate datetime) returns int
begin

 declare@ordinal int,@loopdate datetime

set @loopdate = @TestDateset 
set @ordinal = 0

while datepart(m, @TestDate) = datepart(m, @loopdate)
  begin
            set @ordinal = @ordinal + 1
            set @testdate = dateadd(d, -7, @testdate)
  end

return @ordinal
end
```

ETA: To find the next day of the same ordinal, you'd just keep adding +7 to today's date until fn_ReturnOrdinalDay returned the same result as today, of course.

Comment: HI, I did some math and ended up with this:

ceiling( cast(datepart(day,getdate())as float)/7 )

this will count back from your date to get the ordinal dividing and rounding up

Answer (score 1):

I would use a calendar table to do this: you can populate it with one row per day, and then you only need to write a simple query to answer your question. You can still use the functions and logic suggested by other posters to populate the table, but that would be a one-time task. If you do a lot of work with recurring dates, you can have a column with the string values "first Monday", "third Wednesday" etc. for easier querying.

Your query might look something like this:

```
select 
    min(BaseDate)
from 
    dbo.Calendar
where 
    DayDescription = (select DayDescription from dbo.Calendar where BaseDate = @Today) and
    BaseDate > @Today
```

In other words, give me the first date after today where the DayDescription (i.e. "third Monday" or whatever) is the same as today. That date must be the third Monday of the next month. The exact query would depend on your data types and what the search parameter values are.

As a general observation, many (most?) date-related queries are easier to answer using a pre-populated table than a function.

Comment: thank you man, I bet this would be faster but it won't work for me as I could have dates from today to ten or more years later

Comment: @Milox - why would it not work? You can populate as much data as you need in advance. I have a calendar table with 100 years of data, which is only 36500 rows (plus leap days). It doesn't matter if you populate 10, 100 or 1000 years because it's a one-time task and the data storage is trivial compared to the rest of the database.

Comment: sorry for the delay @Pondlife, I've been working with dates and this seems like a great approach, you're rigth about performance, it will work

Answer (score 0):

If you're only required to do the challenge above then this is relatively easy.

1. figure out the name of the day using the date format function (I can't remember the exact name).
2. Loop from the start of the month and keep a count of the number of, e.g. Tuesdays you come across before you get to your Input date.
3. Then loop over the next month (or whichever month) x number of times, once you have reached the required number, take the next Tuesday

Answer (score 0):

-- For 3rd Wednesday

DATEPART(dw, PromptDate) + DATEPART(dw, PromptDate - 7) + DATEPART(dw, PromptDate - 14) = 12

-- It should not be the 4th or 5th Wednesday as we are interested in 3rd Wednesday only.

AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, PromptDate - 14, PromptDate - 21) <> 0